# How do I add an entry to InputFilter when using a Collection?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to filter and validate each item and validate the whole to check there are no duplicates. There is an arbitrary amount of text inputs in the collection.

```
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'aliasList',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Alias',
            'count' => 2,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'target_element' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text'
            )
        )
    ));
```

I tried adding the code below, but I was crossing my fingers pretty hard. It obviously didn't work. It was hoping there might be an option such as `'oneach' = true`.

```
    $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name' => 'aliasList',
        'required' => false,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
    )));
```

I also intend on adding validators for valid URI and to fail on duplicate. Unfortunately as I'm using ZF2 I think I'm going to be waiting a long time for another ZF2 s̶u̶f̶f̶e̶r̶e̶r̶  developer to come along.

Answer (score 3):

This may not help your problem in a 1:1 ratio, but you may want to try to work around this by adding collections as a fieldset. In **most** cases anything you add into a collection is of a different type and therefore, just by logic, should be on a separate fieldset.

Therefore you may want to try that approach. I assume you know of that blog, in case not here's a very helpful link http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/?p=190

```
 $this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name' => 'categories',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Please choose categories for this product',
        'count' => 2,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'target_element' => array(
            'type' => 'Application\Form\CategoryFieldset'
        )
    )
));
```

This way you add Collection Elements from a Fieldset and the fieldset inputFilters and validators will be added via

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification() {}
```

from the Fieldset-Class.

Comment: That's a great help Sam, thanks. I also ran into trouble with binding the form. It appears that Collection is only expecting target_element to be an element that contains a member named object and breaks otherwise. So binding doesn't work with Collections of standard form elements. see line #481 in ./library/Zend/Form/Element/Collection.php in rc4.

Comment: I removed correct answer for now as I don;t want to put off off the hoards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use smt like:

```
 $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
 $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'aliasList',
    'required' => false,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
    ),
 )));

 $collectionFilter = new CollectionInputFilter();
 $collectionFilter->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
```